# JSON Object can't be converted to JSON Array

Tags: java, jackson, json

ya i know that it's very usual problem while mapping but my problem is some different hear is the scenario 
when my response `have the data` it gives me `JSON Response` like this

```
{
  "responseID": "110",
  "resultSet": [
    {
      "USERNAME": "Aninja",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "60000"
    }
  ],
  "isSuccessful": true,
  "rtnCode": "0000"
}
```

and below is the same `JSON response` `when data is not found`

```
{
  "responseID": "123",
  "resultSet": {},
  "isSuccessful": true,
  "rtnCode": " "
}
```

as i can see hear when response have some data `result set` have `JSON Array` but when no data found we have `JSON Object` as a response

so this is the reason I'm getting this problem.
so my  question is that how should i handle this problem thanks for your response

**Edit:** the main problem is that i have made my model like `list of JSON Object` it works fine when there is result but it gives me error `Can't convert JSON Object to JSON Array` `when result is empty` s please suggest me how can i hanle it I'm using `Jackson 2.2` i have also tried `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` and `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`

Comment: check your reposnse object on the server side, whether the resultSet is a list or not.

Comment: Are you getting JSON response from the server? if yes, then there must be problem in server side. possibly there is a XML to JSON conversion happening at server side.

Comment: but i have to handle this by myself i can't tell to the server side programmer

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is mistake from server or back-end. But it is always a good practice to provide appropriate "Null Object Pattern" which describes the uses of such objects and their behavior.

So for better practice array which doesn't have any values should be sent back using "[]". So in this case "resultSet" should be given as [] instead of {} so it can be easily understood at front-end.

There are number of examples here which shows why it is useful to follow Null Object Pattern.

For example, if you are returning count in you response and there is no count then it is better to use "0" instead of "null".

Comment: actually I'm not developing this services that's why i asked that do i need to teel back-end about this or i can handle this by logics ?Thanks for your response

Comment: you can handle it using try catch block.